# How we get device token in iOS Appcelerator

Tags: ios, titanium, appcelerator-studio

I am using Appcelerator Studio.

I would like to get `device token` from iPhone. I am following the Appcelerator docs, however when the application installed it shows me the alert "do you want receive notification", and after the click on it nothing is printed in console.

Here is my code:

```
var self = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
    backgroundColor : '#146FA6',
    title : 'Menu',
});
var deviceToken = null;
// Check if the device is running iOS 8 or later
if (Ti.Platform.name == "iPhone OS" && parseInt(Ti.Platform.version.split(".")[0]) >= 8) {

    // Wait for user settings to be registered before registering for push notifications
    Ti.App.iOS.addEventListener('usernotificationsettings', function registerForPush() {
        // Remove event listener once registered for push notifications
        Ti.App.iOS.removeEventListener('usernotificationsettings', registerForPush);

        Ti.Network.registerForPushNotifications({
            success : function(e) {
                var deviceToken = e.deviceToken;
                alert(e.deviceToken);
                Ti.API.info("Push notification device token is: " + deviceToken);
                Ti.API.info("Push notification types: " + Titanium.Network.remoteNotificationTypes);
                Ti.API.info("Push notification enabled: " + Titanium.Network.remoteNotificationsEnabled);
            },
            error : deviceTokenError,
            callback : receivePush
        });
    });
    // Register notification types to use
    Ti.App.iOS.registerUserNotificationSettings({
        types : [Ti.App.iOS.USER_NOTIFICATION_TYPE_ALERT, Ti.App.iOS.USER_NOTIFICATION_TYPE_SOUND, Ti.App.iOS.USER_NOTIFICATION_TYPE_BADGE]
    });
}

// For iOS 7 and earlier
else {
    Ti.Network.registerForPushNotifications({
        // Specifies which notifications to receive
        types : [Ti.Network.NOTIFICATION_TYPE_BADGE, Ti.Network.NOTIFICATION_TYPE_ALERT, Ti.Network.NOTIFICATION_TYPE_SOUND],
        success : function(e) {
            var deviceToken = e.deviceToken;
            alert(deviceToken);
            Ti.API.info("Push notification device token is: " + deviceToken);
            Ti.API.info("Push notification types: " + Titanium.Network.remoteNotificationTypes);
            Ti.API.info("Push notification enabled: " + Titanium.Network.remoteNotificationsEnabled);
        },
        error : deviceTokenError,
        callback : receivePush
    });
}
//deviceTokenSuccess();
// Process incoming push notifications
function receivePush(e) {
    alert('Received push: ' + JSON.stringify(e));
}

function deviceTokenError(e) {
    alert('Failed to register for push notifications! ' + e.error);
}

self.open();
```

Comment: Are you using the simulator or a device?

Comment: I am using device.iphone 5s OS (9.2.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If LiveView is enabled, disable it.

There are some known conflicts when using LiveView and push notification services

To disable LiveView function using the Titanium Studio, look at your Appcelerator Studio toolbar, like that

[image]

And deselect the first item.

Comment: how i can disable ListView

Answer (score 1):

The code should be like this

```
var self = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
backgroundColor : '#146FA6',
title : 'Menu',
});

var deviceToken = null;
// Check if the device is running iOS 8 or later
if (Ti.Platform.name == "iPhone OS" &&         parseInt(Ti.Platform.version.split(".")[0]) >= 8) {

// Wait for user settings to be registered before registering for push notifications
Ti.App.iOS.addEventListener('usernotificationsettings', function registerForPush() {

    // Remove event listener once registered for push notifications
    Ti.App.iOS.removeEventListener('usernotificationsettings', registerForPush); 

    Ti.Network.registerForPushNotifications({
        success: deviceTokenSuccess,
        error: deviceTokenError,
        callback: receivePush
    });
});

// Register notification types to use
Ti.App.iOS.registerUserNotificationSettings({
    types: [
        Ti.App.iOS.USER_NOTIFICATION_TYPE_ALERT,
        Ti.App.iOS.USER_NOTIFICATION_TYPE_SOUND,
        Ti.App.iOS.USER_NOTIFICATION_TYPE_BADGE
    ]
});
}

// For iOS 7 and earlier
else {
Ti.Network.registerForPushNotifications({
    // Specifies which notifications to receive
    types: [
        Ti.Network.NOTIFICATION_TYPE_BADGE,
        Ti.Network.NOTIFICATION_TYPE_ALERT,
        Ti.Network.NOTIFICATION_TYPE_SOUND
    ],
    success: deviceTokenSuccess,
    error: deviceTokenError,
    callback: receivePush
});
}
 // Process incoming push notifications
function receivePush(e) {
alert('Received push: ' + JSON.stringify(e));
}
// Save the device token for subsequent API calls
function deviceTokenSuccess(e) {
deviceToken = e.deviceToken;
alert(deviceToken);
Ti.API.info("Push notification device token is: " + deviceToken);
Ti.API.info("Push notification types: " + Titanium.Network.remoteNotificationTypes);
Ti.API.info("Push notification enabled: " + Titanium.Network.remoteNotificationsEnabled);

}
function deviceTokenError(e) {
alert('Failed to register for push notifications! ' + e.error);
}
self.open();
```